# Como faço para dividir itens e diferentes subpaginas na mesma pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Eu queria dividir uns itens em diferentes em **subpáginas**, uma imagem de um exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, se eu clico no **botão 1** ele mostra o **elemento 1**, se eu clico no **botão 2** ele mostra o **elemento 2**, mas isso tudo **sem mudar de página**, exemplo:
site/pagina1, site/pagina2
Eu queria que isso tudo fosse na mesma página, se alguém poder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Cara vc quer realmente uma página .HTML ou .PHP dentro dessa dive, ou vc quer apenas hora mostrar um conteúdo e hora mostrar outro conteúdo, apenas como um sistema de navegação por abas?

Comment: Só quero mostrar o conteúdo quando for clicar no botão 1 e botão 2

Comment: Sim Richard isso deu para etender. O que não ficou muito claro é se esse conteúdo vai ser uma outra página HTML inteira por exemplo, ou apenas um conteúdo simples dentro da página como um texto diferente ou uma imagem

Comment: Um conteúdo simples, uma imagem e algumas tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo simples apenas com CSS que as vezes pode te servir. Não usa JS apenas CSS, Uma dica é antes de usar se atente e estudar as regras CSS e a estrutura do HTML para entender direitinho como funciona tudo. Mas basicamente é um sistema de botões tipo `radio` que quando `checados` mostram o conteúdo.

Se vc estiver usando Bootstrap ele já tem um componente de Abas (*Tabs*) pronto para usar, as vezes pode te ajudar se vc estiver usando, [aqui tem o link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs)

```css
input, .content {
    display: none;
    background: #0084aa;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 1em/150% Sans-Serif;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#one:checked ~ .one,
#two:checked ~ .two,
#three:checked ~ .three {display: block;}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #00a8d8;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 1em/150% Sans-Serif;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: background .25s linear;  
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="nav" id="one" checked="checked"/>
<label for="one">BTN 1</label>

<input type="radio" name="nav" id="two"/>
<label for="two">BTN 2</label>

<input type="radio" name="nav" id="three"/>
<label for="three">BTN 3</label>

<article class="content one">
    <h3>Btn Info 1</h3>
    <p>A bunch of info here.</p>
</article>

<article class="content two">
    <h3>Btn info 2</h3>
    <p>More info here.</p>
    <img src="http://placecage.com/200/200" alt="">
</article>

<article class="content three">
    <h3>Btn info 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit a molestias quo neque, inventore modi beatae debitis vel totam corporis. Doloribus, vitae. Commodi accusantium delectus iste fuga sequi nam molestiae quae sit minima voluptatibus odio velit optio pariatur ipsam dignissimos reprehenderit modi, excepturi ducimus debitis. Perferendis ullam officiis saepe voluptas!</p>
</article>
```

[Fonte de referência](https://codepen.io/scotteesh/pen/DdguJ)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Ficou muito bem explicado.

Comment: @RichardSantos que bom que gostou, se era isso mesmo que vc precisava considere marca a resposta como Aceita, clicando nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) se vc procurar por "Tabs CSS" no Google vc vai encontrar outros exemplos, uns mais simples só com CSS, outros mais complexos com JS e jQuery